# How do I get PyFacebook working with the Google App Engine Patch?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, facebook, app-engine-patch

I've tried to follow the advice of this question: [Facebook, Django, and Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984071/facebook-django-and-google-app-engine), however I've run into a number of problems.  The first is that `from facebook.djangofb import facebook` doesn't work because when I try to use the decorator `@facebook.require_login()`, it complains that the facebook module doesn't have that method.  If I change it to `import facebook.djangofb` and `@facebook.djangofb.require_login()`, it works.  Any ideas that's going on there?

Then, even with that, I experience the same problem as in this question: [app-engine-patch and pyFacebook not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039366/app-engine-patch-and-pyfacebook-not-working).

It seems like a lot of people have done this, so is there a good example of how to combine PyFacebook and App Engine Patch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first question:

> `from facebook.djangofb import facebook` doesn't work because when I try to use the decorator @facebook.require_login(), it complains that the facebook module doesn't have that method. If I change it to `import facebook.djangofb` and `@facebook.djangofb.require_login()`, it works.

Well, seems like `require_login` is on `facebook.djangofb` not on `facebook.djangofb.facebook`.

So you can do:

```
import facebook.djangofb
@facebook.djangofb.require_login()
...
```

or

```
from facebook import djangofb
@djangofb.require_login()
...
```

or

```
from facebook.djangofb import require_login
@require_login()
...
```

For the second question, did you try the answer of the other question (not using *require_login* at all, using `request.fb.check_session(request)` instead)? What do you get?